# FB canvas app Chrome and https

Tags: facebook, canvas, https

Why chrome is not showing my canvas application on facebook ? 
It will show it when you surft direct to it om our domain. But it will give the error below when accessing it it through the apps.facebook.com domain.

We are running on a self signed certificate. Using Firefox on fb canvas app gives you an option if i want to continue surfing an insecure site. Chrome will show an error with no options.

This webpage is not available
might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.

Google chrome version 16.0.912.63 m

Comment: 1/ do you surf FB with secure on? 2/you might want corrects the https://your_fb_app so it does validate as secure. 3/For this one of the things i overlooked was adding FB._https = true;

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved it by going to my local canvas site, exported the certificate (as p7b) and imported it again into Chrome. There was an older local certificate installed, maybe that was the problem.